# Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140

Tags: swift, core-data

I have just started a new project and I am following a Core Data tutorial which can be found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZJpsszfTHM

I can't seem to figure out why this error is being thrown. I have an `entity` called "`Expenses`" in which I have two `attributes`: `Name` and `Amount`. Amount was originally `double` but I have changed it to `String` to follow the tutorial as double was throwing a `SIGABRT` error. I am not using storyboard at all yet and have no other code. Do you have any idea why this error is being caused?

I have closed, restarted, cleaned, deleted the project multiple times and now not using source control but every time I get the same result.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let newExpense = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Expenses", into: context)

        newExpense.setValue("Gym", forKey: "name")
        newExpense.setValue("35", forKey: "amount")

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("SAVED")
        } catch  {

        }

    }

}
```

See here for video: https://media.giphy.com/media/8OVqdFYIK0BFvmEBjL/giphy.gif

Full error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "(null)" UserInfo={sourceModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x600001d14000>) isEditable 0, entities {
Expenses = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600000938c60>) name Expenses, managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier Expenses, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    amount = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600001037000>), name amount, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Expenses, renamingIdentifier amount, va
```

Comment: Could you share the full error error message?

Comment: @Larme edited above

Comment: Look for a better tutorial. State of the art is to create `NSManagedObject` subclasses and assign the values to properties rather than using KVC. The compiler will help you in many cases for example if there is a type or name mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is really peculiar but I got the error because my `product bundle identifier` was not correct. I changed this to another name in the `build settings` and `packaging` and then the error disappears.